# Does using React hooks with `useXXX` make sense?

Tags: discussion

When talking about React hooks, is it understandable when saying

> You should `useFoo` hook...

Or is it better to say

> You should use the `useFoo` hook...

?

I'm not a native English speaker. For me that makes sense, but for the SO community, I'm not that sure about it.

Does using the `use` word of the hook as a word make sense when someone is reading?

Comment: IMO, the first is awful, the second should be *"You should use **the** `useFoo` hook..."*

Comment: @NickA Why is it awful? Could you try to explain it please.

Comment: Because, `useFoo` is a noun in this context, so you would need a verb as well for  the sentence to make sense.

Comment: This question might be a good candidate for the English Language Learners stack (https://ell.stackexchange.com/) =)

Comment: Oh wow. That's a lot of effort put into a few words ... Looking forward to some new high quality answers :)

Comment: Use what you want. Someone may come along and edit it to make sense. Pay attention to those edits and learn from them.

Comment: @Rob or [english.se]. Although I'm not really sure if either deals with how to integrate a programming term as part of speech but if they do, I'd expect English.SE to be the place for it

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think the content in the blockquotes should have been left as is. The edit changed the meaning of the question, and basically incorperates the answer into the question which is usually not done. In my opinion, this change made the first blockquote worse than it was originally.

Comment: @ThomasF thanks, PeterMortensen's edit made my question become really bad, just edited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm no native English speaker, but in my opinion it's better to say the second option with the word the added.

> You should use *the* useFoo hook...

Why? `useFoo` is the name of the hook. That it has the word *use* in the method name has nothing to do with it.

*"You should use the `useFoo` hook"* is actually short for saying: *"You should use the method called `useFoo` to hook into..."* but by using the shorter sentence you convey the meaning as well. That's why the double "use".

Comment: Native English speaker and grammar nerd here… I endorse this answer.